# WinSCP .NET assembly doesn't work on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, winscp, winscp-net

I have problem with WinSCP .NET assembly (NuGet plugin) executing on Azure. All is working on `localhost`, but when I deploy my Web App on Azure I get following error:

> WinSCP process terminated with exit code -1073741819 and output "", without responding (response log file C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mysite\Temp\wscp573C.00D7BA5D.tmp was not created). This could indicate lack of write permissions to the log folder or problems starting WinSCP itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-1073741819` translated to hex is `C0000005`, what is `ACCESS_VIOLATION` error. This probably indicates an internal error of WinSCP.

Make sure you are using the latest version of WinSCP.

If you are already using the latest version, please [report the bug on WinSCP support forum](https://winscp.net/forum/), so that we can fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I had this issue with 5.5.6 but works fine with 5.17.8