# Transfer file from Azure web site to apache

Tags: c#, .net, azure, file-transfer, scp

I have the following problem. I would like to upload files from Azure web site to apache (on linux).

I tried plugins from NuGet gallery: `WinSCP .NET assembly` ([My problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825531/winscp-net-assembly-doesnt-work-on-azure)), and a few others. But are either paid for or do not work properly for SCP.

Is there maybe some other secure way to transfer files using SCP?

Answer (score 0):

The best way for transfer is using SSH.NET from NuGet Gallery.
We can use SCP to transfer and SSH for execute command.

Link for NuGet Gallery plugin: [SSH.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/2013.4.7)